# Gradle reports BUILD SUCCESSFUL, however I can not locate any .class files

Tags: junit, build, gradle, .class-file

I am attempting to use Gradle (for the first time) for a multiproject java build.

I have created a settings.gradle file with all the project names. I have also create a very basic build.gradle file. To my surprise when I run gradle build. It returns BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Jars are created in the build\libs folder. What is puzzling to me is that no .class files exists. Also I have been unable to get any kind of Junit results or xml output.

I'm wondering if this is really building correctly. For now this is my very basic build.gradle file. Any input is appreciated, thanks.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

    version = '1.0'

    compileJava.destinationDir = file("$buildDir/output/classes")

    repositories {

    }

    dependencies {
    }

    test {      
        testLogging {
            exceptionFormat 'full'
            events 'started', 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
        }
    }

    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'gradle'
    }
}
```

As requested this is my project directory structure.

MainProject
build.gradle
settings.gradle
--SubProject1
----src
--Subproject2
----src
.
.
.

Comment: What is your project directory structure like? Where are your source files?

Comment: @PerrynFowler I have a root directory where my settings.gradle and build.gradle sit. This is where I am running my build. Each project then sits in it's own directory with a src directory inside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your subprojects are laid out according to the defaults for the Java plugin

( see section 23.4 Project Layout in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

or tell the plugin where you have put things

( see section 23.4.1. Changing the project layout )