# Gradle build successful, error running jar

Tags: java, spring, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I am new to gradle.

I am building a project using gradle.
It build successfully without any error. While running the build jar file it is giving `classNotFoundException`.

[image]

I am building a [simple](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) spring project from spring.io

However question look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538055/gradle-reports-build-successful-however-i-can-not-locate-any-class-files) but, could not find a solution. Please help.

edit: This is how my `build.gradle` looks

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

startScripts {
  mainClassName = 'Application'
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "Application"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start the application with the generated start scripts. They will automatically take care of setting up the proper classpath.

Comment: thanks! what should it be. My main function is in `Application.java`

Comment: Run `gradle installDist` to create an image of the application in `build/install/projectName`. You'll find the scripts there.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko it gave me a scripts that is around 150 lines long. i am new to this can u tell me how to start the application with those generated start scripts.