# Gradle Build Output Jar Doesn't Run

Tags: java, gradle, jar, classpath

First off, this might be a dupe of [Gradle build successful, error running jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434623/gradle-build-successful-error-running-jar)

I've build a very basic Dropwizard project that is built with Gradle. My `build.gradle` file looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

// use Java 1.8 by default
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// default to UTF-8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// application version and name
mainClassName='com.mydomain.WebServiceApplication'
version = '0.1-' + (System.getenv("SVN_REVISION") == null ? "0" : System.getenv("SVN_REVISION"))
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'WebService',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

// project variables go here
project.ext {
    dropwizardVersion='0.9.1'
}

// repositories that we're getting libraries from
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // compile-time dependencies
    compile (
        'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2',
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'org.logback-extensions:logback-ext-loggly:0.1.4',
        'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.2',
        'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.2'
    )

    // test dependencies - these will be stripped from production jar
    testCompile (
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'junit:junit:4.+'
    )
}

run {
    args 'server', './src/main/resources/config.yml'
}
```

When I run `gradle build`, a `./build/libs/` folder is created that contains a jar called `webservice-0.1.jar`. If I try to execute this jar with `java -jar webservice-0.1.jar`, I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class com.mydomain.WebServiceApplication`.

Thing is, that file most certainly exists. I can do the following:

```
$ makedir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ unzip ../webservice-0.1.jar
$ ls ./com/mydomain/
```

and the file `WebServiceApplication.class` is there. Is there some kind of classpath thing that I have to do in order to get java to find classes inside of my jar? I'm lost here.

Comment: The application plugin can generate a complete app, containing the geneated jar file, its dependencies, and shell scripts to start the app. Use that. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: This question has answers with a few different ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle